# How does the OpenVPN service start connections by default?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, openvpn

I've installed `openvpn` version `2.4.6-xenial0`  from the official [repository](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos). It looks like the service has been automatically enabled:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn.service

# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After reboot, I can see that VPN connections configured in `/etc/openvpn` have been started. However, it's not clear to me from the unit file how that actually happens. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `openvpn` uses a mix of **SysV** and **systemd** scripts.

### TL;DR

This behavior can be configured in the `/etc/default/openvpn`. Here is an extract of the file provided by the `openvpn` package:

```
...
# Start only these VPNs automatically via init script.
# Allowed values are "all", "none" or space separated list of
# names of the VPNs. If empty, "all" is assumed.
# The VPN name refers to the VPN configutation file name.
# i.e. "home" would be /etc/openvpn/home.conf
#
# If you're running systemd, changing this variable will
# require running "systemctl daemon-reload" followed by
# a restart of the openvpn service (if you removed entries
# you may have to stop those manually)
#
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office"
...
```

So `AUTOSTART` is not set, and so all `.conf` files from the `/etc/openvpn` directory are started at boot.

### Using the <s>modern</s> systemd way

1. Set `AUTOSTART="none"` in `/etc/default/openvpn`
2. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Now you can use `systemctl` to manage your openvpn connections, the service are named after the configuration files like this:

`/etc/openvpn/ABC.conf` -> `openvpn@ABC.service`

`/etc/openvpn/XYZ.conf` -> `openvpn@XYZ.service`

And so on...

### Examples

So if you want to start the XYZ openvpn connection, the command should be:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@XYZ
```

To enable this connection on startup :

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn@XYZ
```

To get the status of this connection :

```
sudo systemctl status openvpn@XYZ
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this @pim ! I was tooling around for hours today trying to understand why the documentation at https://www.ivpn.net/setup/gnu-linux-terminal.html wasn't working for me  in trying to run openvpn as a service. I'll definitely point them to this answer in telling them to update their docs!